# How to create an XML file from MySQL Data queries?

Tags: mysql, xml

I would like to know a way to create an XML file using MySQL queries only. without using any scripting language at all.

Are there any books, tutorials on this topic ?

UPDATE:

I would like to clear it out that I want to use sql queries which would forward XML data to a php Script.

Comment: Just found this site:
http://www.xquery.com/xquery/database-support.html
 Can DataDirect Xquery be used to read data from Mysql database and then transform it into a XML file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's [a blog post about returning XML from MySQL SELECT queries](http://eriksdiary.blogspot.com/2007/07/xml-output-from-mysql.html):

```
xml_escape(value) - 
  replace characters not allowed in xml with the escape sequences

xml_attr(name, value) - 
  create an xml attribute 

xml_tag(tagname, tagvalue, attrs, subtags) -
  create a tag
```

And here's [a post about writing the results of a MySQL query to a file](http://www.mattwoodward.com/blog/index.cfm?event=showEntry&entryId=4E6297D9-FB2E-EC27-DA3A1A681243ED7B):

```
SELECT whatever FROM whereever
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Combining these two techniques should let you create an XML file without any scripting.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it quite easily from the command prompt, see this:

http://blog.reindel.com/2007/09/27/output-mysql-query-results-to-xml-from-the-command-prompt/

Comment: Can you help me with it. I am using Toad for MySQL, how do I follow the above tutorial. Its using a Shell. I have never used it before.

Comment: The instructions in that tutorial only apply to the command line mysql tool.