# Fetch and render fetched values from MySQL tables as XML

Tags: python, mysql, xml

I am fetching results out of a query from a table:

```
def getdata()
    self.cursor.execute("....")
    fetchall = self.cursor.fetchall()
    result ={}
    for row in fetchall:
       detail1 = row['mysite']
       details2 = row['url']
       result[detail1] = row
     return result
```

Now I need to process the result set as generated :

```
def genXML()
    data = getdata()
    doc = Document() ""create XML tree structure"""
```

Such that data would hold all the rows as fetched from query and I can extract each column values from it? Somehow I am not getting the desired out. My requirement is to fetch result set via a DB query and store result into a placeholder such that I can easily access it later in other method or locations?

================================================================================

I tried the below technique but still in method 'getXML()' I am unable to get each dict row so that I can traverse and manipulate:

```
        fetchall = self.cursor.fetchall()
        results= []
        result={}
        for row in fetchall:
                result['mysite'] = row['mysite']
                result['mystart'] = row['mystart']
                ..................................
                results.append(result)
        return results

def getXML(self):
        doc = Document()
        charts = doc.createElement("charts")
        doc.appendChild(charts)
        chartData = self.grabChartData()
        for site in chartData:
                print site[??]
```

So how do I get each chartData row values and then I can loop for each?

Note: I found that only last row fetched values are getting printed as in chartData. Say I know that 2 rows are getting returned by the query. Hence in case I print the list in getXML() method like below both rows are same:

```
chartData[0]
chartData[1]
```

How can I uniquely add each result to the list?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092242/how-to-create-an-xml-file-from-mysql-data-queries

Answer (score 0):

Here you are modifying and adding *the same dict* to results over and over again:

```
    result={}
    for row in fetchall:
            result['mysite'] = row['mysite']
            result['mystart'] = row['mystart']
            ..................................
            results.append(result)
```

Create the dictionary inside the loop to solve this:

```
    for row in fetchall:
        result={}
```